# I need to generate and save output of html/css code in JPG with the help of Python

Tags: python, ipython

I want to save to output generated by html/css code in jpg format with the help of python. While googling over this , I have found that we can achieve this using IPython.display.HTML. But this library works only with Python 2.0,which will deprecated in future and So want to achive this with Python 3.0 + , and also need to save the output in JPG generated by html+css code.Can anyone please help, how to achieve this?
Below is the code through which I was able to render html output in python.

```
    #rendering frontend
    
    from IPython.display import display, Image
    IPython.display.HTML(filename='/content/drive/MyDrive/Analysed/Task2/test_page.html')
```

Where , test_page.html file contains simple html css code.

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="mystyle.css">
<title>Hello</title>
<style>
.t{width:100px;height:100px;background-color:green;}
.container{width:1000px;height:700px;border:1px solid black;}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div class="container">
  <div class="t">
    <p>Hello , How's day ?</p>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the output I have get with above code, which i wants to save in jpg
with python.
[html+css rendered output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xLf0X.png)

Comment: Could you help us by adding your code?

Comment: Yes , I have added the code and output

Answer (score 0):

I don't know which OS you're running, but you can `imgkit` for that.

**Installation:** `pip3 install --user imgkit`

**Usage**:

```py
import imgkit
imgkit.from_file("input.html", "output.jpg")
```

Be aware, that you need a working installation of `wkhtmltopdf` for this approach.